# How to remove Minecraft Villager Careers from their Trading Interface

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am a custom mapmaker and I need to know if there is a command to remove the annoying villager careers from their trading interface in minecraft 1.8, or to make a custom villager career.  Is there any way to spawn a custom villager that has no career/custom career?

Comment: Rename them perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean just the display name, then a custom name will replace it:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"A Villager",Career:1}
```

If you mean to prevent careers from affecting trades (since trading will refresh trades based on their career), then you need to set their "Career" to a non-0 value that also corresponds to their "Profession" (a value of 1 covers all professions), as well as set their "CareerLevel" to a value higher than the 'maximum' level for that career (which varies).

For example, the following villager will never create new trades.

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"A Villager",Career:1,CareerLevel:100}
```

Comment: This works than you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently *not* a way to recreate the careers of villagers in-game, vanilla; Although, I'm sure MCEdit or something related can do something similar. Possibly a Bukkit plugin, but I'm sure there's a way of doing it, just not in Vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: thanks for contributing to arqade, you could improve your answer substantially by doing a little research and adding details of the mod required that you mention in your post.