# How do I hide the name text on a mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon custom Villagers for my minecraft adventure map that I am making.
I figured out that to hide their career from their trading interface that you have to give them a custom name, but I only want the custom name to show in the trading interface and not when you hover over them. ([Previous Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240930/how-to-remove-minecraft-villager-careers-from-their-trading-interface))

However when I do:

> `/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:Bob,CustomNameVisible:0}`

Their Custom Name still shows.  I don't know if this is a result of the way the CustomName tag works for mobs, or not.  If anyone could explain this that would help a lot.

Comment: What Minecraft version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An entity will not display its CustomName if there is another entity on top of it. For example, you can summon the villager with an invisible ArmmorStand on top of it:

**In version 1.9 or higher:**

```
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:Bob,Passengers:[{id:ArmorStand,Invisible:1b,Marker:1b}]}
```

**In versions 1.8 or lower:**

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Marker:1b,Riding:{id:Villager,CustomName:Bob}}
```

Comment: I suggest making the armor stand into a `Marker` as well, to get rid of the hitbox.

Comment: @MrLemon Good point; added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

### 1.13+ Update

Above answer still applies, however command syntax and format were changed in 1.13+.

1.13 command:

```
/summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"Bob"}',Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:armor_stand",Invisible:1b,Marker:1b}]}
```